# What are best practices when writing (sub)equations?

Tags: notation, article-writing

I wonder when it's preferred or better to use subequations instead of normal equations. I.e. when to use 'normally' numbered equations (e.g. (1), (2), ...) and when to use subequations (e.g. (1a), (1b), (2a), (2b), (2c), ...).

I can think of a few situations when to use subequations:

1. Expansion/abbreviation, e.g.

   > We have
   >   $$y = x+x,\quad(1a)$$
   >   which can be simplified to
   >   $$y = 2x.\quad(1b)$$
2. Combination of equations, e.g.:

   > We calculate force F using
   >   $$ F = m*a,\quad(2a)$$
   >   and work W with
   >   $$ W = F\cdot s.\quad(2b)$$
   >   Combining eqs. (2a) and (2b) gives
   >   $$ W = m\cdot a\cdot s.\quad(2c)$$

There are other examples, certainly. I'm not sure why 'normally' numbered equations without letters aren't simply used. Is there a general guideline or best practice?

Comment: Where is the problem with $(1)$ and be simplified to $(2)$. $(3)$ and $(4)$ combine to $(5)$? Unless having a very long document, where equation numbers are usually chapter-scoped $(\text{Chapter}.\text{Equation})$, the standard is using the default numbering scheme regardless of inner relations of equations.

Comment: I personally never use subequations. Complicated labels produce complicated documents, and the reader might prefer a single, progressive number to indentify uniquely an equation.

Comment: Whatever you choose, you should typeset the labels over by the right margin, so that they are easy for the reader to see and to find, and clearly separate from the equation itself.  For example, $$W = F\cdot s.\tag{2b}$$ instead of $$W = F\cdot s.\quad{(2b)}$$

Comment: Ok, thanks! I know the number is better aligned to the right of the page, I didn't know how to easily type it. My examples were just about the number, not their position. I was just wondering what would be reasons for the use of subnumbers/letters. I also thought: why not simply use one sequence? It is indeed easier on the reader.